# Problem converting hex string to Bytes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I cannot convert String to Bytes.

I try to convert a string (`'55 55 00 00'`) in hex format to bytes and send those bytes out via Pyserial, but i found i have error on string to bytes conversion. My code is:

```
msg = '55 55 00 00'

bytes.fromhex(msg)
```

I expected the result should be `b'\0x55\0x55\0x00\0x00'`, why is the result
`b'UU\x00\x00'`.

What is `UU`?

Comment: `chr(0x55) = 'U'`...

Comment: Indeed; Python only prints bytes as hex sequences if they're not printable ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

`0x55` is the same as the ASCII code for the letter `U`. So Python is doing the right thing.
One way of seeing this is:

```
b'\x55' == b'U'
True
```

Comment: Thank you all , I get it

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly converted the `msg` string into Python 3's `bytes`  string/object. You are just confusing from its console print. **The bytes object is actually a sequence of short integers, though prints its content as characters whenever possible.**

To check below:

```
In [49]: msg = '55 55 00 00'
In [50]: values = bytes.fromhex(msg)
In [51]: values
Out[51]: b'UU\x00\x00' # U == \0x55 == 85
In [52]: values[0]
Out[52]: 85
In [53]: [value for value in values]
Out[53]: [85, 85, 0, 0]
```

Note: here `85 == 0x55` that is possible to print as `U`

Suppose if something is not possible to be print as character then it would be printed as escaped hex values, check below:

```
In [54]: bytes("aÄBèC", sys.getdefaultencoding())
Out[54]: b'a\xc3\x84B\xc3\xa8C'
```

Further, to print in your desired format you have to explicitly write code to print:-

```
"".join(["0x{:02x}".format(value) for value in values])
```